# Mysql returning empty set when data is there

Tags: mysql

I have a simple locations table with the columns: `location_id, country, state, city`.

I populated the table with data and ran the following query:

```
SELECT location_id 
FROM locations 
WHERE country="United States" 
AND state="Louisiana" 
AND city="New Orleans";
```

MySQL returns an empty set even though the data is there. I've isolated it to the city column. If I leave off the city condition in the WHERE clause everything is fine. If I ask for the city in the SELECT clause but not in the WHERE clause everything is fine. What could be the problem? This query seems too simple to be causing trouble.

Could white space in the city column be causing this?

UPDATE! UPDATE!

THANKS EVERYONE - I SOLVED THE PROBLEM.
I entered the city column data from text files with each city name being on a line by itself. This got me wondering about the newline character. I ran the query (SELECT location_id FROM locations WHERE state="Louisiana" AND city="New Orleans\n"). Worked like a charm.

I cleaned all the newlines out of the column by running this query:
UPDATE `locations` SET `city` = REPLACE(REPLACE(`city`, '\r', ''), '\n', '');

Everything works fine and I learned a trick about using text files to populate a database.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me solve this weird problem.

Comment: can you do a select * and include results in question?

Comment: Can you output result of folowing SQL for the row you cannot find? SELECT CONCAT('"', location_id, '"') AS location_id, CONCAT('"', country, '"') AS country, CONCAT('"', state, '"') AS state, CONCAT('"', city, '"') AS city FROM locations;

Comment: Can you add the script that creates your table and the inserts of your data?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it rather than editing your question. That way it'll appear as resolved and other people will be able to find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the white space; United States is also two words. I'd browse the table to look for spelling errors or other typos.

You can ensure you don't have a problem with leading or trailing white space, or with capitalization like this:

```
SELECT location_id
FROM locations
WHERE lcase(trim(country))="united states"
AND lcase(trim(state))="louisiana"
AND lcase(trim((city))="new orleans"
```

Comment: if "New Orleans" comes from a web form add lcase and trim to both sides of the =. Like this `lcase(trim((city))=lcase(trim(<web form data>))`

Answer (score 1):

does city equal Exactly "New Orleans"? Or is there a space? or capitalization issue? Try

```
trim(city) like 'new orleans'
```

Comment: Doing a double wild card search in MySQL is never advisable as it will force the MySQL engine to ignore all indices.

Comment: The trim function had no effect, even if I used it on all the WHERE values. Select * returns everything, including the city. I checked my data. Everything is spelled correctly and there are no white spaces. I've been doing mysql for years and never had a problem with such a simple situation. Thanks everyone for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the city column may have some sort of extra space in the column's data and your collation is somehow affecting this. Try doing:

```
SELECT location_id 
FROM locations 
WHERE country="United States" 
AND state="Louisiana" 
AND trim(city)="New Orleans";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT location_id 
FROM locations 
WHERE country="United States" 
AND state="Louisiana" 
AND city LIKE "New Orleans%";
```

Comment: That worked but it seems like I shouldn't have to use a LIKE to get this query to work. There must be something wrong somewhere. Plus I only want to return 1 row. Some town names appear in multiple states.

Comment: There is probably extraneous data at the end of the city field, that is why it is not coming up in an exact match.  You can do an update on all fields replacing `city = trim(city)`

Comment: Is city a char instead of a varchar?

Comment: Trim is definitely probably the better solution here barring the problem being a data type issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes instead of double. 'New Orleans'